# Как сформировать php-config на Debian

Tags: php

Отсутствует файл php-config на Debian.
sudo apt-get install php5-dev - не помогает. Файл по прежнему отсутcтвует.
В чем проблема?

Answer (score 0):

В пакете [`php5-dev`](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/amd64/php5-dev/filelist) есть `/usr/bin/php-config5`. Это должен быть именно он.

Если вам необходимо, чтобы команда была доступна именно как `php-config`, то проще всего сделать симлинк.

Comment: После установки php5-dev этот файл /usr/bin/php-config5 также отсутcтвует.

Comment: Какой релиз дебиана и версия пакета?